# clear the session cache on demand laravel 5.0

Tags: laravel-5

am using laravel 5.0 with file session driver
I am having a  problem while trying to clear the session cache upon request (on demand)

More precisely, how to make a manual call  to the function `gc()` of the class `FileSessionHandler.php` in order to clear expired sessions

Answer (score 0):

I used this in my controller :

```
use Illuminate\Session\FileSessionHandler;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;

public function clearSessionTest()
    {
     $app= App::getFacadeRoot();
     $path = $app['config']['session.files'];
     $fileSession=new FileSessionHandler($app['files'], $path);
     $fileSession->gc(10);
    }
```